Path exists between the two vertices of odd degree
This question appeared in my test of design and analysis of algorithms and I wrote the following proof , but my instructor says I went wrong somewhere. Why is my proof incorrect ?
Q. Comment about the correctness of the following statement and justify your  answer. A simple graph G having exactly two vertices of odd degree must contain a path from one to the other.
Given: A simple graph G, having exactly two vertices of odd degree . Let the two vertices of odd degree be a and b.
To prove: Graph G contains a path from a to b
Proof:
Let the two vertices of odd degree be a and b.
To show that the graph G contains a path from a to b, we show that such a path exists by construction.
Algorithm to trace the required path:
Start at a ; since a has odd degree there exists at least one edge with one end on a. We traverse one of the edges and reach a vertex v .
Vertex v has either an odd degree or even degree.
Case 1: If v has odd degree then  we have successfully reached b.
Case 2: If v has even degree then one of the edges of v was used to reach v from a. Number of edges except the edge used to reach v = degree(v) - 1.
Since, degree(v) is even , degree(v) - 1 would be odd. Thus, there exists at least one edge except the edge used to reach v. We take any one of the remaining edges and reach some vertex .
Subsequently, we follow any of the edges except the previously traversed edges.
Proof that there exists at least one edge we can use to exit the vertex at some stage
Let that vertex be traversed i number of times before, 2 edges would be used (one to enter and the other to exit).
One edge would be used to the enter the vertex at this stage
Number of untraversed (available) edges = degree of vertex - 2i - 1 = Even - odd = odd
Since, Number of untraversed edges is odd,  there exists at least one edge which we traverse.
We terminate when we reach a vertex of odd degree.
Proof that algorithm terminates
Whenever we reach a vertex of even degree, we have shown that  at least one edge we can use to exit the vertex. So the algorithm will never terminate at a vertex of even degree.

You say "proof that the algorithm terminates", but you do not prove that it terminates. Instead, you just note that it cannot terminate at a vertex of even degree. You need to argue that it must terminate (a very simple observation will handle this), and to prove that it also cannot terminate at $a$.

A non-constructive proof is to note that any graph must have an even number of vertices of odd degree. To show this, cut all the edges in half and count the half-edges by summing the vertex degrees. Now, the component of $a$ in $G$ (the set of all vertices and edges reachable from $a$) forms a graph that includes $a$ and thus must include a second vertex of odd degree.
